# Revert the results of rails scaffolding in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

When a model is generated in rails - let's say to keep records for users, then we also get a route/controller/view for handling these (CRUD). Therefore visiting "root_url/users" would list all the users, "root_url/users/1" would display the first user etc.

While this is handy in a dev environment, it's not inappropriate for production (currently production for me is Heroku).

I could just remove the extra controllers, views etc. but I was wondering whether there is a standard way of approaching this issue (like a flag in a config file) so that there isn't a mismatch between dev and production.

Comment: Could you elaborate it pls what you wanna achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a standard way of approaching this issue, it's called testing, code review, and generellay just doing what is required for your application to work.

Scaffolding code is a good thing, but you just have to use it when it's needed. If you commit often enough, you can scaffold and easily reset what you've done if it does not meet your need.

It is your responsibility to not put any code in production :)